# How do I set an Edit Text back to it's original state

Tags: java, android

I have a simple calculator app. When the user presses calculate the edit text where they entered their number changes color and outputs the result. When reset is pressed I would like the line under the edit text to re-appear but it doesn't show up the way I current have my code written. This is a snipped of my current code.

```
    @Override
public void onClick(View v){
 switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.calculate:

            myFunction.doWork();

            voltageInputEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
            voltageInputEditText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

            break;

        case R.id.reset:

            myFunction.reset();

            voltageInputEditText.setText("");
            voltageInputEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

            break;
        }
}
```

This is the desired result

[image: Desired Look]

This is the current result

[image: Current Result View]

This is the look after I run myFunction.(doWork);

[image: Post Function Look]

Comment: Unable to open the Google+ link

Comment: Can you post the Use case that you are trying to replicate (eg: Step wise description for reproducing your issue)

Comment: Using something like imgur is your best bet for posting images.

Comment: I have edited the original post to include the images @Kakarot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `setBackgroundColor` internally it is calling `setBackgroundDrawable` with a ColorDrawable, so you're replacing the original background, the one that displays the line inside EditText.

Setting a white background color to begin with would equally remove this line.

It should work if you save the original background drawable via `getBackground` and later restore it via `setBackgroundDrawable`.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply save it.

```
String savedInputText = "";

@Override
public void onClick(View v){
switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.calculate:

        myFunction.doWork();

        savedInputText = voltageInputEditText.getText();

        voltageInputEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        voltageInputEditText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        break;

    case R.id.reset:

        myFunction.reset();

        voltageInputEditText.setText(savedInputText);
        voltageInputEditText.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        break;
    }
}
```